# "Cannot find symbol" for tester program

Tags: java

I'm supposed to make two java programs that are related, Account.java

```
public class Account {
// Declarations
String Number = "null";
String Type = "null";
String Card = "null";
String Date = "null";

protected Account() {

}

public String toString() {
    return "\n\t Your account number is " + Number + ",your account type is " + Type + ",your card number is " + Card
            + ".\n\t your expireation date is: " + Date;
}

protected String getNumber() {
    return Number;
}

protected void setNumber(String number) {
    this.Number = number;
}

protected String getType() {
    return Type;
}

protected void setType(String type) {
    this.Type = type;
}

protected String getCard() {
    return Card;
}

protected void setCard(String card) {
    this.Card = card;
}

protected String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

protected void setDate(String date) {
    this.Date = date;
}  }
```

and AccountTester.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AccountTester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create Objects
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Account a = new Account();

    // auto with nothing set
    System.out.print("Your account information is curently set to" + a
            + "\n\n");

    // set info for account
    System.out.print("Please, enter your account number: \t");
    a.setNumber(s.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Please, enter your account type: \t");
    a.setType(s.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Please, enter your card number: \t");
    a.setCard(s.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Please, enter your expire date: \t");
    a.setDate(s.nextLine());

    System.out.print(a);

} }
```

The first code has no problems, but in the 2nd code in the line that says

```
"Account a = new Account();"
```

it shows an error saying "cannot find symbol, symbol class Account, location class accountTester".
I tried changing it to

```
"AccountTester a = new Account();"
```

But it not only did it not fix it, but it also made all the codes with "a.set" give out the same "cannot find symbol" error. How can I fix this

Comment: Your constructor should be `public`, not `protected`.

Comment: @JacobG. Doesn't matter if they are in the same package. Since they are probably both in the unnamed package, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Are the two `.java` files in the same directory? How are you compiling them?

Comment: *FYI:* Java naming convention is for field names to start with lowercase letter.

Comment: @Andreas if it's a `cannot find symbol`, I assume the classes aren't in the same package and OP isn't importing `Account`.

Comment: @JacobG. Since OP is showing `import` statement, then OP would likely also have shown `package` statement if it had been there. It's not, so fair *assumption* is that both are in the unnamed package. But I did say "if" and "probably", since I'm guessing. You didn't condition your comment, and it's only correct for some scenarios, which is why I added my comment clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a model and you want to import your model POJO `Account` to be used in another java classes in a different package of the package where you created the class. if it so, please change all your `protected` methods to `public` methods. That's because when you are importing the class and then construct it. Java cannot create your model because at runtime there is no access. Please change it. here is a link for more information.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private)

To work, it has to be in the same package!!

I hope to help you!!

Comment: I changed all the protected methods to public, put them into the same directory and called it unit4_ASimmions, and put "package unit4_ASimmions at the start of each code, but still no luck.

Comment: Do you put it in the same package??

Comment: Don't you import it into the class, do you?? you have to import it!!